# Add JSON element in existing JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I know JSON does not work by index like an array, but i'm looking for a way to add a new JSON element on a specific position within the JSON object.

Let's say i have an array with JSON objects:

```
[
    {
        "key": value,
        "key": value,
        "key": value,
    },
    {
        "key": value,
        "key": value,
        "key": value,
    }
]
```

And i want to add a new element in each JSON object on the second position.

```
[
    {
        "key": value,
        ** Enter new key/value here **
        "key": value,
        "key": value,
    },
    {
        "key": value,
        ** Enter new key/value here **
        "key": value,
        "key": value,
    }
]
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: json uses key-value-pairs. its not supposed to place elements by order.

Comment: You can't do that with this type of data. You can create a custom class to solve your problem

Comment: It's obviously invalid JSON

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects (upon which JSON is based) do not remember insertion order.

If serialization/deserialization is not needed, you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects, which have key=>value pairs with insertion order.

In case you need to serialize/deserialize, then its better to convert the JSON object, to a JSON array of single pair objects, instead like `[{"a":"z"}, {"b":"y"}, {"c","x}]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in JSON as order by key or value.
It works as key-value-pairs